# Databinding in Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, blend

I have found an excellent [video](http://www.msdev.com/directory/Description.aspx?eventId=588) about how to bind controls to an XML dataset completly in Blend without a single line of code.

I am trying to do the same - bind a textbox to a value of Dataset --> MyDataSet.xsd which grabs the total number of rows in a table (executes: select count(id) from books). And I am having a hard time doing this in Expression Blend 4. I know how to databind from code-behind file, but this time I really want to achieve the same results without writing a single line of code or messing with my XAML.